# REACT: Customize checkbox to show/hide columns of a table

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I'm trying to customize the buttons selectors of columns with checkboxes. The table is made it with

```
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import ToolkitProvider from "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit";
```

I have creacted the checkboxes and checked by default only three of them, but this selection has no effect over the table. Why?

On the other hand, If I make clic over a checkbox, this click show or hide the column correctly, but it doesn't appear the checkbox checked or unchecked. Why?

What am I doing wrong?

You've got all the code here:

[image: Edit Custom checkbuttons]

How can I fix my mistakes?

Comment: Because of this: `checked={index < 3 ? true : false}`
Only first 4 checkboxex will be checked, others won't.
You need to change this prop dynamically, don't rely on columns indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is wrong, just remove it, or close and it will work:

```
checked={index < 3 ? true : false}
```

EDIT: For first 3 columns must be something like this.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import ToolkitProvider from "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {
  const columns = [
    {
      dataField: "id",
      text: "Product ID",
      hidden: true
    },
    {
      dataField: "name",
      text: "Product Name",
      hidden: true
    },
    {
      dataField: "price",
      text: "Product Price",
      hidden: true
    },
    {
      dataField: "field1",
      text: "Field 1"
    },
    {
      dataField: "field2",
      text: "Field 2"
    },
    {
      dataField: "field3",
      text: "Field 3"
    },
    {
      dataField: "field4",
      text: "Field 4"
    },
    {
      dataField: "field5",
      text: "Field 5"
    },
    {
      dataField: "field6",
      text: "Field 6"
    },
    {
      dataField: "field7",
      text: "Field 7"
    },
    {
      dataField: "field8",
      text: "Field 8"
    },
    {
      dataField: "field9",
      text: "Field 9"
    },
    {
      dataField: "field10",
      text: "Field 10"
    },
    {
      dataField: "field11",
      text: "Field 11"
    },
    {
      dataField: "field12",
      text: "Field 12"
    }
  ];

  const products = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Producto 1",
      price: 3.45,
      field1: 1,
      field2: 2,
      field3: 3,
      field4: 4,
      field5: 5,
      field6: 6,
      field7: 7,
      field8: 8,
      field9: 9,
      field10: 10,
      field11: 11,
      field12: 12
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Producto 2",
      price: 4.45,
      field1: 1,
      field2: 2,
      field3: 3,
      field4: 4,
      field5: 5,
      field6: 6,
      field7: 7,
      field8: 8,
      field9: 9,
      field10: 10,
      field11: 11,
      field12: 12
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Producto 3",
      price: 5.45,
      field1: 1,
      field2: 2,
      field3: 3,
      field4: 4,
      field5: 5,
      field6: 6,
      field7: 7,
      field8: 8,
      field9: 9,
      field10: 10,
      field11: 11,
      field12: 12
    }
  ];

  const CustomToggleList = ({ columns, onColumnToggle, toggles }) => (
    /*     <div
      className="btn-group btn-group-toggle btn-group-vertical"
      data-toggle="buttons"
    >
      {columns
        .map(column => ({
          ...column,
          toggle: toggles[column.dataField]
        }))
        .map(column => (
          <button
            type="button"
            key={column.dataField}
            className={`btn btn-warning ${column.toggle ? "active" : ""}`}
            data-toggle="button"
            aria-pressed={column.toggle ? "true" : "false"}
            onClick={() => onColumnToggle(column.dataField)}
          >
            {column.text}
          </button>
        ))}
    </div> */
    <div className = "text-center">
      {columns
        .map(column => ({
          ...column,
          toggle: toggles[column.dataField]
        }))
        .map((column, index) => (
            <Form.Check
              type="checkbox"
              key = {column.dataField}
              inline
              label={column.text}
              id={column.dataField}
              //aria-pressed={(column.toggle) ? "true" : "false"}
              checked={column.toggle}
              aria-checked={ column.toggle ? "true" : "false"}
              onChange = {() => onColumnToggle(column.dataField)}
              //onClick={() => onColumnToggle(column.dataField)}
            />
        ))}
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <ToolkitProvider
        keyField="id"
        data={products}
        columns={columns}
        columnToggle
      >
        {props => (
          <div>
            <CustomToggleList {...props.columnToggleProps} />
            <hr />
            <BootstrapTable {...props.baseProps} />
          </div>
        )}
      </ToolkitProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It works!!! But, how can I set by default for example the first three columns? I mean, how can I show by default only the colums Product ID, Product Name, Product Price?